# Flexslider view with pictures from nodes tagged with a taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, javascript

I need to group 10 images (random choice) of nodes belonging to a content type, and belonging to taxonomy *foo* with the term bar, **in a Flexslider**. How can I  setup that content pane view ?

Precision : each node can have one up to ten images.

I created a content view,

- with that image field
- Filtered by content type
- Sort criteria : Global Random
- Contextual filter : Content : taxonomy foo(provide default value : taxonomy term ID from URL)

If I use format unformatted list / display all items, it gives me a list of expected images. But if I use Flexslider format, **it groups all the images of a single node in each slide !** I understand that the query result is grouped by nodes, when I just need its images ...

### View preview

[image]

Comment: Is the image field in the content type a multivalue field or do you have single fields for the images?

Comment: @Volker, it's a multi value field indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the "Multiple field settings" in the view image field configuration. Try to uncheck "Display all values in the same row".

[image]

Comment: My bad, you're right :)

Comment: Don't worry, we all overlook things... :) Glad it worked.